# gsettings or dconf value list for a key

Tags: dconf, gsettings

I want to list all the values available for the screensaver:

```
dconf list /org/cinnamon/desktop/screensaver/ | grep matrix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was a enumeration, you could

```
gsettings range ...
```

Reference: `man gsettings`

From: `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.cinnamon.desktop.screensaver.gschema.xml`, it declared a `string` (`type="s"`). Means it does not have a range.

```
<key type="s" name="xscreensaver-hack">
  <default>"fiberlamp"</default>
  <summary>The screensaver hack to use when xscreensaver is used as screensaver</summary>
</key>
```

Anyway, It is an xscreenshot related option, you can see available hacks using:

`dpkg -L xscreensaver-data` or more precisely `ls /usr/share/xscreensaver/config/ | xargs basename -s .xml`

```
abstractile
binaryring
cwaves
deco
distort
fiberlamp
fuzzyflakes
galaxy
hexadrop
m6502
metaballs
penrose
popsquares
ripples
shadebobs
slidescreen
swirl
tessellimage
xlyap
```

Comment: Good enough `ls /usr/share/xscreensaver/config/ | xargs basename -s .xml | grep -i matrix` gives 
`glmatrix
xmatrix`

Answer (score 4):

Re. `gsettings`,

```
gsettings list-recursively
```

lists all the "schemas" along with keys and values. You can pipe the output to `grep` like this:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i screensaver
```

Your output may differ from mine:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i screensaver
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-opacity 100
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-delay uint32 7200
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver primary-color '#023c88'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver secondary-color '#5789ca'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-command ''
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver color-shading-type 'solid'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-command ''
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver show-notifications false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-options 'zoom'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver show-full-name-in-top-bar true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/adwaita-lock.jpg'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver status-message-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver user-switch-enabled true
apps.light-locker lock-after-screensaver uint32 5
$
```

I don't use `cinnamon` and don't know how the commands I've provided will work!

Comment: It lists the schemas and keys but not the values. `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i matrix` gives
`org.cinnamon.desktop.screensaver xscreensaver-hack 'glmatrix'`

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for. If this has nothing to do with your question, maybe make it more clear.

```
dconf read /org/cinnamon/desktop/screensaver/xscreensaver-hack
```

This may also help:

```
dconf list /org/cinnamon/desktop/screensaver/
```